# How to correct slight imprecisions in QGIS georeferenced .tiff raster images?

Tags: raster, qgis, geotiff

Is there a QGIS plugin or tool to slightly drag or stretch a georeferenced raster, to better fit the base map ?

Typically an issue with GPS or drone images, they are georeferenced, but often come with a few meters offset, or are a bit short on a side, etc.

I know how to georeference a raster image from scratch, or how to use GCPs within the drone mapping software, but both are not always perfect either...

*You can find this kind of tools in Gimp or Photoshop, using a frame or a grid to deform the image (instead of points in QGIS georeferencing plugin).*